# Right out of the box, my HP laptop displays "disk (SMART event) is at risk" error in Intel Optane Memory and Storage

Tags: hard-drive, memory, windows-11

[image]

**My Lapop Information:**
HP 14t-dq200 
i5-1135G7 + Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics 
8 GB DDR4-2666 SDRAM (2x4GB) 
512 GB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 Value SSD

**S.M.A.R.T. Information from CrystalDiskInfo**:
[image]

I searched for a solution online. Some have suggested an error check on my disk.

[image]

I did that, but I still couldn't resolve the issue. I've contacted HP technical support, their tech support personnel deleted files in %temp%. They viewed the Reliability Monitor. But they were not able to resolve the issue... Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

My main concern is whether this is a *serious problem* (As Tonny mentioned "the SSD can fail completely at any time")

**UPDATE**:
Today Intel Optane Memory and Storage reported this error 5 times in a short duration of time. Now my D and E partitions have disappeared.

[image]

[image]

**Replying to harrymc:**
It's weird. When I looked in the Intel Optane Memory and Storage Management software, it shows me the driver version is 18.6.1.1016. Is this the RST driver information?

[image]

[The link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19755/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-8th-and-9th-gen-platforms.html?v=t) you sent me shows that the latest driver is 17.11.0.1000. Does that mean my computer has a newer driver than the Intel website? Or that's not the right place to look for RST driver information?

Comment: Please specifiy the exact model of the HP laptop. There are several versions op Optane SSD and memory and without knowing the model of your laptop we can't guess which it is. And it is important to know that in order to suggest further troubleshooting.

Comment: @spacenet - Edit your question to include that vital information

Comment: Return it for a refund

Comment: I just watch the sales ads in my area, takes time but you can find a deal.

Comment: @Moab So this is a serious issue?

Comment: Sure it is, When I buy a New laptop I expect it to work, not me having to work on it

Comment: @Moab Sorry, what I meant by "serious" is that the laptop's hardware is defective. It's not simply a driver issue that I can fix by updating an outdated driver. Do you concur with Tonny's answer that it's serious because it "can fail completely at any time"?

Comment: It does not matter, send it back now.

Comment: Please include in your post a screenshot of the S.M.A.R.T. Information from CrystalDiskInfo for the disk. Do you have installed the latest [Intel RST driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19755/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-8th-and-9th-gen-platforms.html?v=t) version 17.11.0.1000?

Comment: Please answer the comment.

Comment: Thank you @harrymc I've updated the S.M.A.R.T. Information from CrystalDiskInfo. Where do I look for my current RST driver information? I looked in Intel Optane Memory and Storage Management software. It showed me the driver version is 18.6.1.1016. Does that mean my computer has a newer driver than the Intel website?

Comment: I was misled by google - your disk is newer and your driver is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially the M.2 SSD in your laptop is not just an SSD, but also contains a 16 GB RAM chip that acts as an extra disk-cache.
The Optane driver software glues these together so Windows considers the combination to be a single device.

Now the Optane software thinks there is an error, but a SMART test on the SSD part is fine.
This indicates a problem with the RAM cache, which will usually not go away by itself. And it may get worse suddenly.

First of all: Make a backup of anything important on that laptop as the SSD can fail completely at any time if this problem gets worse.
(And personally I would not consider this laptop to be reliable at all with this error.)

Try updating all bios/firmware/drivers with the latest version from the HP website. Sometimes a thing like this is a glitch that disappears with an update, so that may help.

It it doesn't go way after updates call HP again and make this a warranty issue. Get the SSD replaced. (That also means a re-install of Windows. Another reason for the backup I mentioned.)
If the helpdesk isn't very helpful be persistent and get this escalated.
They should replace the SSD under warranty. A recurring error like this is just unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tony. Are you saying in addition to the 8GB ram, the SSD has another 16GB RAM? (So 24GB total? I've never heard of such config in the past) HP technical support now requests me to contact their HP Smart Friend, a paid support because support regarding this issue is not covered under the complimentary phone/ chat support. Wtf... What's a better way to get this issue escalated?

Comment: The extra 16 GB cache-RAM is inside the SSD module and is NOT usable as normal RAM. So you don't really have 24 GB RAM available. Paid support ?? WTF. The laptop is broken and under warranty (it is too new to be out of warranty). Don't accept that. Call again. Don't accept paid support. It is not a support issue. It is a warranty claim. You need a repair. If they try to send you to paid support again demand to talk to a supervisor. You may have to get really nasty on the phone. The other option is to go for a refund (if possible in your location). Laptop is not fit for purpose.

Comment: They won't escalate to a supervisor citing that "since we are working from Home. we do not have the manager right now." Errr, how is it possible that the company is still doing well...

Comment: Tony, thanks for your help. It looks like you're right about the hardware. My D and E partitions have disappeared. Software installed on those 2 partitions can no long be found. I want to award you the +50 rep, but it looks like I've missed the deadline. Is the 50 rep permanently gone?

Comment: This is nonsense, far more likely the Intel software hasn't got a clue about the Samsung SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Samsung
[lists](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/ssd/client-ssd/)
your disk as a normal NVMe SSD disk.

As you don't have Intel SSD with Optane in your laptop, the
Intel Optane Memory and Storage Management is irrelevant for you and
should be uninstalled. The notifications are just bogus.

The SMART data of your disk shows that it is in absolutely perfect shape
with not even the least error event.

However, the data lists 11 "Unsafe Shutdowns". These mean that power
was brutally cut to the disk, the firmware trying to save data with
the last electric resources in its accumulators.

As you have lost two partitions, it seems that the power cuts were not
totally recovered by the firmware.

I would suggest examining the power problem on your end.
I don't know if the computer is being turned off at the mains,
but it should rather be shut down in a regular manner.
If the electric supply in your environment is irregular, you should
protect the computer with a UPS.

If you don't have any electric problems at your place, the only conclusion
left is that the disk is defective and should be replaced.

Comment: From where did you get the information that I had 11 unsafe shutdowns? I've not done a hard shutdown once...

Comment: From the "Unsafe Shutdowns" parameter. As I said, if there are no electric problems at your place or inside your computer, the disk should be replaced. This is only prudent, after having lost two partitions.

Comment: Exactly. Upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

A "SMART event" suggests a SMART value reported by the HDD itself has crossed a threshold, i.e. a potential hardware issue (dozens of SMART values are typically monitored). Unless the value in question relates to bad sectors, it won't show up with a chkdsk scan.

Try checking the drive with CrystalDiskInfo to see which one it is: https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/

You may also want to run the on board HP diagnostics, make sure the tests include the HDD (I think they're in the default set though). I would be suspicious of a system drive that spits out errors, and diagnostics results should help you get HP to replace it under warranty.

Comment: I ran CrystalDiskInfo, SSD's heath status came out as "Good."

Comment: @spacenet This may not be conclusive as Optane can be a combination of Cache-RAM and SSD. If the cache part has issues a SMART test on the SSD will not show it.